# Windowed DirectX app not drawing on multi monitor setup

Tags: c++, directx

I have developed a simple 2D directX game engine which can create a window of any size. I want to be able to develop games to run on multi monitor setups. The setup I am trying to use is two monitors both at 1024 x 768. I have developed games using Clanlib which is OpenGL and all I did was create one large window 2048 x 768 and run it without borders, which worked perfect.

In my engine I use the following styles if the user states the window should be borderless:

- dwStyle = WS_POPUP;
- dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE ;

The problem im having is strange. When I run an application that has a window size of 2048 x 768 and its set to border less on my development computer which is windows 7 its works perfect.

When I run it on a different machine running XP the left monitor flashes up the normal graphics then just goes black and never recovers. Its like its lost the device context. Im puzzled because it doesn't happen on my development computer. Could it be the drivers for the graphics card or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.